# MySQLi Prepared Statement Multiple execute()

Tags: php, mysqli

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","eradmin","eradmin","employrank",8889);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }       

    $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null;
    $add = isset($_POST['add']) ? $_POST['add'] : null;

    if($id != null){
        $stmt = $con->prepare('update contestants set score = score + 1 where id = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    if($add != null){
        $ln =  isset($_POST['ln']) ? $_POST['ln'] : null;
        $fn =  isset($_POST['fn']) ? $_POST['fn'] : null;
        $dv =  isset($_POST['div']) ? $_POST['div'] : null;
        $sr =  isset($_POST['scr']) ? $_POST['scr'] : null;
        $stmtAdd = $con->prepare('insert into contestants(ID, last_name, first_name, dept, score) values (DEFAULT,?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $stmtAdd->bind_param('ssii', $ln, $fn, $div, $scr);
        $stmtAdd->execute();
    }
```

The stmt executes fine. But the stmtAdd doesn't get executed. I placed echos and it does make it there. Not sure what it could be.

Comment: Is "ID" auto_increment?

Comment: `$div` wrong variable. Do `$dv`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure ID isn't an AI. (*Just an insight*)

However, you're using the wrong variables `$div` and `$scr` in:

```
$stmtAdd->bind_param('ssii', $ln, $fn, $div, $scr);
```

which should read as `$dv` and `$sr` *respectively*.

```
$stmtAdd->bind_param('ssii', $ln, $fn, $dv, $sr);
```

as per what you presently have:

```
$dv =  isset($_POST['div']) ? $_POST['div'] : null;
```

and

```
$sr =  isset($_POST['scr']) ? $_POST['scr'] : null;
```

---

- Having used [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would have signaled those undefined variables.

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that was it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: According to Mysql docs DEFAULT for numeric column with AUTOINCREMENT is the next value in sequence. Doesn't that work here?

Comment: @Delphy I spotted another `$scr` which should have been `$sr`. Reload my answer please.

Comment: @hakre I just thought I'd cover all the bases. But the variables were indeed the main cause.